# Need Regex pattern for right side of 10 digits from mobile Number

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help with how to write a regex for getting the last 10 digits from the right side of the mobile Number

For examples:

Input  is: 919345678901
output is:  9345678901

input2 is: 09934567892
output is: 9934567892

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PL/SQL means *Oracle*; in that case, you don't need slow regular expressions as fast `substr` function does the job nicely:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '919345678901' from dual union all
  3     select '09934567892'  from dual
  4    )
```

Query begins here:

```
  5  select col,
  6         substr(col, -10) result
  7  from test;

COL          RESULT
------------ ----------------------------------------
919345678901 9345678901
09934567892  9934567892

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
regexp_replace(target,'^\d*(\d{10})$', '\1')
```